# Setting custom runtime classpath for a maven project in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, configuration, classpath

I want to add a custom classpath when I'm running my maven project from within netbeans. So far I've tried adding the following to the **Run Project** action in the project properties:

```
exec.args=-classpath %classpath;c:/QUASR/duplicateRemoval.jar;c:/QUASR/lib/QUASR.jar ${packageClassName} 

exec.args=-cp %classpath;c:/QUASR/duplicateRemoval.jar;c:/QUASR/lib/QUASR.jar ${packageClassName}

exec.args=-cp c:/QUASR/duplicateRemoval.jar;c:/QUASR/lib/QUASR.jar ${packageClassName}
```

but no luck, the custom runtime classpath is not set.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a new profile `run-with-netbeans` in your pom that declares the additional dependencies (use the `provided` scope to not include them in the release).

Then you'll have to add the new profile to your IDE to run the pom with the `-P run-with-netbeans` option in the command line.

```
<properties>
    <!-- provided by default -->
    <my-dynamic-scope>provided</my-dynamic-scope>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>run-with-netbeans</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- compile when running in IDE -->
            <my-dynamic-scope>compile</my-dynamic-scope>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        <scope>${my-dynamic-scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The snippet above add log4j only when running with the `run-with-netbeans` profile. It also sets a property `my-dynamic-scope` that can be used in your dependency block to change the scope.

HIH
M.

Comment: Could some one expand on this Answer? This is exactly what I want to do, include a library during programming & compiling but not include in the build. I'm a little familiar with editing a POM file, but I've no idea how to do these steps.

Comment: Similar Question, [Include a library while programming & compiling, but exclude from build, in NetBeans Maven-based project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32087445/642706) with good Answer.