# Set a classpath just for jUnit in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, junit, classpath

I am using Netbeans for my Java project and I am getting started with jUnit.  However, I find that it is not configuring the db correctly because it can't find certain resources.  Is there a way to add a classpath for it to use went running jUnit so I can configure it to find all the resources?

Comment: The Question is not clear, so it may be a duplicate of [Setting custom runtime classpath for a maven project in netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11615164/642706).